# Is it possible to retrieve the last file of a folder in C language without using popen?

Tags: c

it's been a long time since I touched C. I'm trying to get the name of the last file created in a folder. In a daemon I get the live file number with scandir, however I can not get the timestamp of the files in the dirent.
Do you have an idea ? I do not want to use popen () and a bash command.
(thank you for your answers and sorry for the approximate english)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cjson/cJSON.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){

  int pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0){
      perror("Echec lors du clonage.");
      exit(-1);
   }
    else if (pid > 0){
          printf("Service lancé sur le PID : %d \n", pid);
          exit(0);
      }

      time_t debut, fin, difference;
      int numOfFiles = 0, oldNumOfFiles = 0, i  = 0;
      char *path = "/home/ackbar/Documents/watchmen/testfolder";
      debut = time (NULL);

      while(1 == 1){
          i++;
          struct dirent **fileListTemp;
          int numOfFiles = scandir(path, &fileListTemp, NULL, alphasort);

          if((numOfFiles > oldNumOfFiles) && (oldNumOfFiles == 0)){
            printf("first -\n");
            oldNumOfFiles  = numOfFiles;
          }
          else if(numOfFiles < oldNumOfFiles){
            printf("delete -\n");
            oldNumOfFiles  = numOfFiles;

          }
          else if(numOfFiles > oldNumOfFiles){

              printf("%d -- add %d\n", oldNumOfFiles, numOfFiles);
              oldNumOfFiles  = numOfFiles;
          }

          fin = time (NULL);
          difference = difftime (fin, debut);
          if((int)difference > 120){
            printf("fin\n");
            break;
          }

   }
}
```

Comment: _I can not get the timestamp of the files in the dirent. Do you have an idea ?_: yes, use a `stat` call on the file paths

Comment: The code read the folder repeatedly. This will create lot of load on the system. What are you trying to achieve ? Is this some form or (build your own) inotify watch ?

Comment: @dash-o yes this is a inotify like for listen SFTP upload. How would you limit the load? I had put a sleep (1) but when the files arrive almost instantaneously I have losses.

Comment: @Jean-François thanks you i'll read the doc !

Comment: Consider putting a sub-second sleep usleep(microseconds) ; (e.g. usleep(100000)). It will reduce load, while still allowing you to detect changes quickly.

Comment: @VinceMatsui the question ask on how to get the timestamp of the `last` file. Given that you are implementing a directory watcher, are you looking for max(timestamp) of newly added files ? Can you extra details in the question to clarify this requirement. It's not clear from the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, @ Jean-François I managed with stat actually. I will add the link to the git of what I am doing. I think it's not perfect (I'm not C developer), but I tried to pay attention to memory leaks and low-level issues.